# Close tab with Python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, safari

Im trying to refresh a number of listing I have on a website and then close the tab.

I have this set to run every hour and it works perfectly for me, I know it may be the most stupid code to everyone else but it does what I need it to do. All I need now is for it to close the tab after it opens the link. Currently I come to my laptop and there is 50+ tabs open.

```
import webbrowser
import time

start = "https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/advert_renew.pl? 
advert_id="
end = "&flatshare_type=offered"
nums = ['13549393', '13292512', '13787806', '13787662', '11924089']
nums2 = ['12755839', '5467930', '3844433', '12950809', '9187090', '11834794', '8017675', '5154283', '12418570', '12459514']



for num in nums:
url = start+num+end
webbrowser.open_new(url)
#print(url)
time.sleep(2)


for num in nums2:
url = start+num+end
webbrowser.get('safari').open_new_tab(url)
#print(url)
time.sleep(2)
```

Everything technically works. It just needs to close the tab after it opens it.

Currently using both Brave Browser and Safari but happy to use two others and 'Quit' those applications if that works better.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. See below.

```
browser.quit()
```